# PHPMYADMIN. Как проверить на дубликат при импорте CSV?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста. Я импортирую через phpmyadmin csv файл. Проверка на дубликат идёт только по столбцу ID почему-то хотя в любом случае у меня ID различается. Надо по другому слобцу выполнять проверку.
Как бы это реализовать? Изменить тип столбца? Спасибо заранее

Comment: Контроль дубликатов выполняется созданием уникального индекса по тому полю, комбинации полей или выражению, дублирование коих надо запретить.

Comment: Добрый день. Да вот догадался, но получаю ошибку #1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'kp_id_movie'

Comment: Ошибку выполнения конкретного запроса можно обсуждать лишь тогда, когда опубликованы структуры таблиц, полный текст запроса и полный текст ошибки. В вопросе, а не в комментариях.